# How can I infer the return type without a type variable?

Tags: typescript

My goal is to create a function, that clones an array - and keeps the types. With this code, typescript declares the return type as any:

```js
export function someFn(inputArray) {
    return [...inputArray];
}
// result will have any[] as type
const result = someFn([1, 2, 3]);
```

How can I tell typescript, that the return type of `someFn` will be the same type as the input (i.e. in this case, an array of numbers?

**Workaround**

I know I can do this with a type variable:

```js
export function someFn<T>(inputArray): T[] {
    return [...inputArray];
}
// result will have number[] as type (but only because I input T as number)
const result = someFn<number>([1, 2, 3]);
```

I would like to avoid the above workaround because it forces me to declare the type beforehand.

Comment: I'm not sure why a generic is undesirable [seems to work fine](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAZzgWwKYDEwB4AqAfABQxgAOIUAggE60CGAngFyL4DaAugJRuddEAbwBQicYloYoIWkg4A6JWUo16zLgG4RAXxEB6fZIzIQAGyiIA7jDNnEACwYA3DIjAg0AIwy1uiBmREKCZyN2IvKkQEMyZEHwgGEGQ3AElEFSj8AKCPb18eEQgEZEspUwtEAF4UdGwwYg4ARgAaRAAmNoBmXm0gA).

Comment: I was missing the `T[]` on the function's parameter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you type the argument as anything that depends on `T` (in the example below `T[]`), the generic will be inferred from the argument, without the need to  specify it upon calling:

```
function someFn<T>(inputArray: T[]): T[] {
  return [...inputArray];
}

const result = someFn([1, 2, 3]); // `result` will be of type `number[]`
```

Answer (score 2):

Even though you say you don't want to use a generic type, that's the correct answer. However your declaration doesn't make full use of it:

```
export function someFn<T>(inputArray: T[]): T[] {
    return [...inputArray];
}

const numberResult: number[] = someFn([1, 2, 3]);       //correct
const stringResult: string[] = someFn(["a", "b", "c"]); //correct
const mixedResult: string[] = someFn(["a", 2]);         //error
```

[TypeScript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAMwK4DsDGMCWEVwM4QC2wAYigDwAqAfABSYphIwCCUUAhgJ4BcclAbQC6ASj6ChcAN4AoOPLhRgMJFFwCAdFoZNW7bkIDcMgL4yZaHHngokhAEbAoAJWB4kAGxh9bDp8LgAXnwiUhRaAQBGABo4ACZYgGZRQwU0gHp0y3ZgDAsreGsoBgBzV3cvPiLSgOCCYjIIgCIOJtim+za4JrQmlLhM7KU8yxRrOEJMEGAAE3LPb3wYYpQS2pCG8IEWrrj+tIz0pyhoGSA)

If you declare that the output would be the an array of the same type as the input, you don't need to explicitly specify the generic type argument.

Comment: What is your point of the last item mixedResult, indicating `//error` - do you mean that the type should have been `string | number[]`? I understand now - you can illustrate the typescript understands that this will not be the type - makes sense now just had to open the playground.

Comment: It means that if you try to assign a `(number | string)[]` to a `string[]`, Typescript will complain

Comment: @DauleDK because `mixedResult` is declared as `string[]`. Wanted to show that you maintain type safety, as `someFn` produces `(string | number)[]` and not just a string array.